# how to play video file from database in mvc?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

i want to play video files like .mp4 , .3gp . .avi and flv in my asp.net mvc application
My video files saved in the database . Is stored as bytes

now how can i display this files list and w
How can I show my video preview after the select for play like the youtube

Comment: Is database the best place for videos? At least I would just save them to the file system somewhere and add the location into the database.

Comment: For security reasons and the possibility of moving the files I have stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of articles online regarding your question and here is one that you can use http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Save-Retrieve-and-Play-MP4-Video-files-with-live-streaming-from-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: i don't want to download my file from database before play - like as live stream

Comment: In this case I thin you should cache the file on disk which will give you the NTFS performance also you can using the [bit rate throttling](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/bit-rate-throttling) to improve the performance of your streaming solution

Comment: Thank's Hossam .
now i'm looking for free straem player for display mp4 , flv , 3gp and avi mime type file . Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: You can use the following player http://flvplayer.com/, I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to play video file from Database / PC

```
<div width="320" height="240" controls>
      <video>
             <source src="@Url.Content(Model.tbl_Video.VideoPath)" type='video/mp4' />
      </video>
</div>
```

source property needs to pass url not the string,

so @Url.Content converts the path as Url

Hope this helps!